# Algorithm to find min and max in a given set

Tags: c++, algorithm

A large array `array[n]` of integers is given as input. Two index values are given - `start,end`. It is desired to **find very quickly** - `min & max in the set [start,end]` (inclusive) and `max in the rest of array` (excluding [start,end]).

eg-

array - 3 4 2 2 1 3 12 5 7 9 7 10 1 5 2 3 1 1

start,end - 2,7

min,max in [2,7] -- 1,12

max in rest - 10

I cannot think of anything better than linear. But this is not good enough as `n is of order 10^5` and the number of such find operations is also of the same order.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to look at the value of each element, so there is no way you can do better than linear.

Comment: You can do a linear search on 0 to `start`, then `start` to `end`, then `end` to the last element of the array. You only have to search once through every element. Save information as you're going through each loop, checking for the various things you're looking for in each segment (the min/max in the range and the max in the rest). That will prevent multiple loops. After that, it has to be linear.

Comment: 10^5 are "small" data, so I wouldn´t be worried with linear complexity.

Comment: it is required to perform the find operation 10^5 times.

Comment: You could sort the data as you read it in. Then the min and max of any sub range is simply the first and last element of the range.

It depends on what is more important: finding the min/max quickly and often, or reading in the data quickly. If finding the min/max is important, then spend the extra effort to pre-process the data.

Comment: Depending an the actual input, sorting the three parts _may_ be faster, since they are smaller than n. You can have the three sorting steps in parallel so you gain another boost from that. In general however, there isn't a better algorithm than O(n).

Comment: Is that homework? BTW, the number of find operations and what may change for them is also part of the problem specification (I suppose only the bounds `start` and `end` change, but not the array).

Comment: Is your array an ordered array or an associative array? The method I described in my answer works for associative array. If it is fixed, then indeed, threading with divide-and-conquer is the best solution.

Alternatively you can keep min/max each time you add a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a data structure that will answer min and max queries for intervals on an array quickly.

You want to build two [segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) on your input array; one for answering interval minimum queries and one for answering interval maximum queries.  This takes linear preprocessing, linear extra space, and allows queries to take logarithmic time.

Comment: @aclap you got what you were looking for?

Comment: Constant-time lookup is possible: htp://wcipeg.com/wiki/Range_minimum_query gives several algorithms. The optimal is linear preprocessing time plus constant query time.

Comment: @misterbee: That looks terrifying to code up.  Is it actually faster on arrays of OP's size?

Comment: I don't know of any comparison between existing implementations or estimates from constant factors.

Answer (score 6):

The way I understand your question is that you want to do some preprocessing on a fixed array that then makes your find max operation very fast.

This answers describes an approach that does O(nlogn) preprocessing work, followed by O(1) work for each query.

### Preprocessing O(nlogn)

The idea is to prepare two 2d arrays BIG[a,k] and SMALL[a,k] where

```
1. BIG[a,k] is the max of the 2^k elements starting at a
2. SMALL[a,k] is the min of the 2^k elements starting at a
```

You can compute this arrays in a recursive way by starting at k==0 and then building up the value for each higher element by combining two previous elements together.

```
BIG[a,k] = max(BIG[a,k-1] , BIG[a+2^(k-1),k-1])
SMALL[a,k] = min(SMALL[a,k-1] , SMALL[a+2^(k-1),k-1])
```

### Lookup O(1) per query

You are then able to instantly find the max and min for any range by combining 2 preprepared answers.

Suppose you want to find the max for elements from 100 to 133.
You already know the max of 32 elements 100 to 131 (in BIG[100,5]) and also the max of 32 elements from 102 to 133 (in BIG[102,5]) so you can find the largest of these to get the answer.

The same logic applies for the minimum.  You can always find two overlapping prepared answers that will combine to give the answer you need.

Comment: What about the space complexity?

Comment: Needs O(nlogn) space to hold the preprocessed arrays.  (If this is too much, then an alternative is to store the array only at positions that are multiples of 2^k. In this case, the space and preprocessing time become O(n), but the lookup becomes O(logn))

Comment: +1, Yes space complexity is little large (~32 times n for a 10^5 array) but I think locality of reference will be good so search will be really fast.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid, that there is no faster way. Your data is completly random, and in that way, you have to go through every value.
Even sorting wont help you, because its at best O(n log n), so its slower. You cant use bisection method, because data are not sorted. If you start building data structures (like heap), it will again be O(n log n) at the best.

Answer (score 2):

If the array is very large, then split it into partitions and use threads to do a linear check of each partition. Then do min/max with the results from the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for min and max in an unsorted array can only be optimized by taking two values at a time and comparing them to each other first:

```
register int min, max, i;
min = max = array[0] ;

for(i = 1; i + 1 < length; i += 2)
{
    if(array[i] < array[i+1])
    {
        if(min > array[i]) min = array[i];
        if(max < array[i+1]) max = array[i+1];
    }
    else
    {
        if(min > array[i+1]) min = array[i];
        if(max < array[i]) max = array[i+1];
    }
}

if(i < length)
    if(min > array[i]) min = array[i];
    else if(max < array[i]) max = array[i];
```

But I don't believe it's actually faster. Consider writing it in assembly.

EDIT:
When comparing strings, this algorithm **could** make the difference!

Answer (score 0):

If you kinda know the min you can test from x to min if the value exists in the array. If you kinda know the max, you can test (backwards) from y to max, if the value exists in array, you found max.

For example, from your array, I will assume you have only positive integers.:

```
array - 3 4 2 2 1 3 12 5 7 9 7 10 1 5 2 3 1 1
```

You set x to be 0, test if 0 exists, doesn't, you then change it to 1, you find 1. there is your min.
You set y to be 15 (arbitrary large number): exists? no. set to 14. exists? no, set to 13. exists? no. set to 12. exists? yes! there is your max! I just made 4 comparisons.

If y exists from the first try, you might have tested a value INSIDE the array. So you test it again with y + length / 2. Assume you found the center of the array, so decal it a bit. If again you found the value from the first try, it might be within the array.

If you have negative and/or float values, this technique does not work :)

Comment: I dont see improvement, you still have to iterate whole array. "Guessing" can not be used as reliable method, it wont be 100% accurate.

Comment: numbers can be in the range 1-10^8.

Comment: No I do not. if the array starts from 10 to 59, I iterate from 0 to 10 and from, say 70 to 59. The array is semantically sorted.

Comment: @aclap Then you put x from 0 and y from 10^8+1

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not possible to have sub-linear algorithm (as far as I know) to search the way you want. However, you can achieve sub-linear time is some cases by storing fixed ranges of min-max and with some knowledge of the range you can improve search time.
e.g. if you know that 'most' of the time range of search will be say 10 then you can store min-max of 10/2 = 5 elements separately and index those ranges. During search you have to find the superset of ranges that can subsume search-range.

e.g. in the example
array - 3 4 2 2 1 3 12 5 7 9 7 10 1 5 2 3 1 1

start,end - 2,7

min,max in [2,7] -- 1,12

if you 'know' that most of the time search range would be 5 elements then, you can index the min-max beforehand like: since 5/2 = 2,

```
0-1  min-max (3,4)
2-3  min-max (2,2)
4-5  min-max (1,3)
6-7  min-max (5,12)
...
```

I think, this method will work better when ranges are large so that storing min-max avoids some searches.

To search min-max [2-7] you have to search the stored indexes like: 2/2 = 1 to 7/2 = 3,
then min of mins(2,1,5) will give you the minimum (1) and max of maxes (2,3,12) will give you the maximum(12). In case of overlap you will have to search only the corner indexes (linearly). Still it could avoid several searches I think.

It is possible that this algorithm is slower than linear search (because linear search has a very good locality of reference) so I would advise you to measure them first.

Answer (score -1):

Linear is the best you can do, and its relatively easy to prove it.

Assume an infinite amount instantaneous memory storage and costless access, just so we can ignore them.

Furthermore, we'll assume away your task of finding min/max in a substring.  We will think of them both as essentially the exact same mechanical problem.  One just magically keeping track of the numbers smaller than other numbers in a comparison, and one magically keeping track of the numbers bigger than in a comparison.  This action is assumed to be costless.

Lets then assume away the min/max of the sub-array problem, because its just the same problem as the min/max of any array, and we'll magically assume that it is solved and  as part of our general action of finding the max in the bigger array.  We can do this by assuming that the biggest number in the entire array is in fact the first number we look at by some magical fluke, and it is also the biggest number in the sub-array, and also happens to be the smallest number in the sub-array, but we just don't happen to know how lucky we are.  How can we find out?

The least work we have to do is one comparison between it and every other number in the array to prove it is the biggest/smallest.  This is the only action we are assuming has a cost.

How many comparisons do we have to do?  We'll let N be the length of the array, and the total number of operations for any length N is N - 1.  As we add elements to the array, the number of comparisons scales at the same rate even if all of our widely outrageous assumptions held true.

So we've arrived at the point where N is both the length of the array, and the determinant of the increasing cost of the best possible operation in our wildly unrealistic best case scenario.

Your operation scales with N in the best case scenario.  I'm sorry.

/sorting the inputs must be more expensive than this minimal operation, so it would only be applicable if you were doing the operation multiple times, and had no way of storing the actual results, which doesn't seem likely, because 10^5 answers is not exactly taxing.

//multithreading and the like is all well and good too, just assume away any cost of doing so, and divide N by the number of threads.  The best algorithm possible still scales linearly however.

///I'm guessing it would in fact have to be a particularly curious phenomenon for anything to ever scale better than linearly without assuming things about the data...stackoverflowers?

Comment: Read the comments; he's doing this repeatedly.

Comment: That seems like an ambiguous interpretation at best.  We don't know whether its 10^5 operations on the one array, or 10^5 operations because he's doing it on 10^5 arrays.  I'm interpreting it as the second, which i accept could be wrong...

Comment: its 10^5 operations on one array and I think its pretty clear from the question.